# Create instance of classes of owl ontology and save them in rdf store

Tags: rdf, jena, owl

I generated OWL ontology using Protege. I want to use my OWL ontology and create the RDF triples to be saved in a triple store using Jena.

I know how to read/write RDF,but i dont know how to create  instances for those OWL class(s). For example:

sample OWL ontology I have

```xml
   <owl:Class rdf:about="Person"/>
   <owl:Class rdf:about="Animal"/>

   <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="salary">
     <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="Person"/>
     <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;real"/>
   </owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

RDF required is something like that

```xml
    <Person rdf:about="Jack">
      <salary>1234</salary> 
    </Person>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create instances programmatically using the Jena Ontology API. There are two ways this can be done. Both require you to provide an [`OntClass` object](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html) and an [`OntModel`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html)

1. Call the [`createIndividual`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html#createIndividual%28%29) method on an `OntClass`  object.

   ```
   OntClass class = ontModel.createClass( yourNamespace + "SomeClass" );
   Individual instance = class.createIndividual( yourNamespace + "individual1");
   ```
2. Call the [`createIndividual`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#createIndividual%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource%29) method on an `OntModel`object and pass an `OntClass` object as an argument.

   ```
   OntClass class = ontModel.createClass( yourNamespace + "SomeClass");
   Individual individual = ontModel.createIndividual( yourNameSpace + "individual2", class);
   ```

For more information, you can visit the [official tutorial for Jena Ontology API](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/)

Comment: Thank you, but this is just intances, how to use these do not create rdf triples using these instances.

Answer (score 2):

Approach #1
When you parse OWL using Jena or Sesame, you'll get the owl in form of triples in either a Model or a Graph. And these triples can be stored in a triplet store.

Approach #2
You can solve this problem by creating the instances in the form of triples. Following is the sample java code. Please note that I did not test this code and this is just for understanding.

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append(" xmlns:drug=\"http://www.healthcare.com/patient/drug#\"");
sb.append(" xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\"");

sb.append("compliance:treatmensub rdf:resource=\"http://www.healthcare.com/patient/drug##id_pa_"+id+"*pr*"+"_"+drugname+"\"/>");

but I suggest approach #1 to follow as you have an OWL file.